# Javascript files won't reload? Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: javascript, ubuntu

I have this problem with my web server will not reload our javascript files when we eg overwrite with a new one, if for example, we have made ​​a mistake in the previous file. 
If we just throw a file on top of the same name, update the file does not, we will have to create a new file with a different name.

Anyone have a solution to it?

Comment: "Ubuntu" ? That's not the problem. What do you use to serve the files ?

Comment: How do you realize that file didn't change? browsing the site from outside of checking the file on the server file system? It sounds like a http caching issue...

Comment: Browsing outside, and yes it might be something about caching,

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Ubuntu nor JavaScript, but browser (or server?) caching.

The simplest way to force the non-cached version to be used is to add a version to your file when you update it, using a query string like this:

```
<script src="myScript.js?v=2"></script>
```

If you wish to **always** force the non-cached version, you can use the timestamp instead and get something like:

```
<script src="myScript.js?t=1407845240"></script>
```

Browsers will see these are different files and always load them from scratch. Both `t` and `v` are custom variables, so you can use whatever you want there - it's important that their value changes with each new version of the file (or automatic, if you're using the timestamp method).

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in your browser to refresh the page will force it to get your new JS file.